# Where does `docker-compose logs` pull from?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, laradock

Like most people who downvoted the sparse [Docker docs page here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/) and [here](http://laradock.io/documentation/#view-the-log-files), I'm confused by what `docker-compose logs` does.

When I run `cd /apps/laradock/ && docker-compose logs -f nginx`, I see a very long output from many days ago til now.

What file or files is that pulling from?

The only nginx log file I could find was `/apps/laradock/logs/nginx/error.log`, and it doesn't have much in it (so isn't the same).

And is there a way to "log rotate" or otherwise ensure that I don't spend more than a certain amount of disk on logging?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the default logging driver, [json-file](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/), your logs are stored in `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/`. Do note that what gets logged here is the output of stdout and stderr from PID 1 of your container.

As for "log rotate", the json-file driver has some options you can pass to it to limit the size per log file, and the maximum number of log files. See `max-size`, and `max-file` of the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/#options).

With docker-compose, you can set the options like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  myservice:
    image: ...
    logging:
      options:
        max-file: "3"
        max-size: "50m"
```

Comment: This answer seems like it would be in the right direction, but I just looked at my `docker-compose.yml`, and it says `version: '2.1'` and doesn't have the word "logging" anywhere in the file. And I don't *think* the what I see when I run `docker-compose logs -f nginx` is JSON format. Any idea where I should look to see how my current logging is configured? Thanks.

Comment: The logs are stored as json on disk. But when you run `docker-compose logs`, it knows to parse the json and just output the raw text.

And the compose version is just an example. Version 2.1 supports `logging` field.

Your compose file doesn't have "logging" because it is leaving everything at the default (ie. no log rotation).

Answer (score 5):

It depends which [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) is used.

You can check which one is configured for the Docker daemon with:

```
docker info -f '{{.LoggingDriver}}'
```

The default driver [json-file](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/) logs to:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log
```

Docker compose then aggregates the logs for each container in the docker-compose.yml.